# value.length inside for loop not working. mongoose ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Im having issues getting .length working inside a for loop using node.js ejs and mongoose. I would like to loop over some objects in mongodb and then loop over arrays within each object. Im also skipping the first object in the database as this is a template object. I outline the problem below. (i have removed the <% %> mongoose tags from the code for clarity )

db name = exes

objects look like this in mongodb:

```
Exe.create({
    user: "Marc", 
    exercise: ["Exercise", "Bench Press"],
    previous: [0, 0],
});
```

Just as test data there are 3 objects all the same. the user is always just one name and the exercise and previous (weight) are arrays. My code looks like this.

```
exes.forEach(function(exercise, index){ // irritate over each object
    if (index < 1){ // Ignore first object in DB
        return;
    }else{
        exercise.user // Print username from object
        for (var i = 0; i = exercise.exercise.length; i++){
            exercise.exercise[i] // print [i] item from exercise array
        }
    }
});
```

This is how my code looks but the page just wont load and after it times out i get this error in my console.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  114564 ms: Scavenge 823.4 (839.2) -> 815.5 (839.2) MB, 0.1 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].
  114611 ms: Scavenge 823.4 (839.2) -> 815.5 (839.2) MB, 0.1 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].
  114657 ms: Scavenge 823.4 (839.2) -> 815.5 (839.2) MB, 0.1 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].
  114704 ms: Scavenge 823.4 (839.2) -> 815.5 (839.2) MB, 0.1 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].
  114755 ms: Scavenge 823.4 (839.2) -> 815.5 (839.2) MB, 0.1 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x5302113fa99 <JS Object>
    2: /* anonymous */ [0x53021104241 <undefined>:~22] [pc=0x33b7f9be87c] (this=0x12055783d541 <JS Global Object>,exercise=0x3b15653927a9 <a model with map 0x260077d5c781>,index=1)
    3: arguments adaptor frame: 3->2
    4: InnerArrayForEach(aka InnerArrayForEach) [native array.js:942] [pc=0x33b7f74fdb0] (this=0x53021104241 <undefined>,bq=0x3b1565392921 <JS Function (SharedFunctionInfo 0x1a9413...

FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x109cafc [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::AllocateUninitializedFixedArray(int) [node]
 6: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int) [node]
 7: 0xc4bc93 [node]
 8: 0x9eb29d [node]
 9: v8::internal::Runtime_ArrayPush(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
10: 0x33b7f7062bf
Aborted
```

However, if i remove the for loop and just print out exercise.exercise.length like so:

```
exes.forEach(function(exercise, index){ // irritate over each object
    if (index < 1){ // Ignore first object in DB
        return;
    }else{
        exercise.user // Print username from object
        exercise.exercise.length // print how many objects are in the array
    }
});
```

i do infact get the value 2 returned for each object. So why does it not assign i = array length in the for loop? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i = exercise.exercise.length; i++){
```

should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < exercise.exercise.length; i++){
```

Your current code is resetting the loop index to exercise.length over and over.  That's what's creating the infinite loop. The line in the middle of the loop should indicate the condition for continuing or stopping the loop.  In this case, the loop should only continue if i is less than (<) the size of the array because the array indexes go from 0 to array length-1.

Comment: OH MY GOD, Thank you. silly typo. thank you so much!